# How can I put Google Ads in a flash game?

Tags: game-design, flash, facebook

What I want to do is put Google Ads in my flash game.

The first question is how can I do that?

The second question is the best place to put it; while loading, after finishing the game?
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Last I checked you cannot embed Google Adsense in a Flash game/app, because Adsense is HTML+JS, which cannot be put inside Flash.

You could hover it over your Flash game...but there are compatibility issues, doesn't work on all OS/Browsers, and may cause UI bugs with your Flash game.

You could try hacking the Adsense code so that it requests the ad data and loads it & displays it inside Flash...but this is against their terms of service.

Your only option with Adsense is to place them on the same page next to your flash game (which isn't an option if you need your game to take up the full page). I suggest looking at [Mochi ads](http://en.mochimedia.com/developers/), they are specifically designed to be embedded in flash games.

---

Edit: A user posted a link to [Google Adsense for Flash Games](http://www.google.com/ads/games/publishers.html)...unfortunately they have quite strict requirements, which most people wont meet.

Current Requirements:

1. Game plays: Minimum 500,000 per day
2. Game types: Web-based Flash only
3. Integration: Must be technically capable of SDK integration
4. Traffic source: Must be 80% US & UK Traffic
5. Content: Family safe and targeted at users age 13 and up
6. Distribution: Must be able to report embed destination and have control over where games are distributed

Comment: First thanks for your post , there are games like who has the biggest brain put the ads after finishing the game , the image in the main post , i guess they used HTML code maybe in TextField or they used URLRequest , i don't know :(.

Comment: Actually, Google AdSense has specific code for embedding in flash, and other games: http://www.google.com/ads/games/publishers.html

Comment: @DrDeth huh, never heard of that before. Too bad 99% of all web games don't qualify... "Current Requirements: # Game plays: Minimum 500,000 per day # Traffic source: Must be 80% US & UK Traffic # Distribution: Must be able to report embed destination and have control over where games are distributed"

Comment: @DrDeth  as Mr.davr said it's impossible to reach these numbers ,are there any Alternatives solutions as  Mochi ads ?

Comment: Ahh... sorry about that. I wasn't aware of the requirements - they seem absolutely ridiculous. A quick google search yields quite a few alternatives: http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=in+game+advertising

Comment: please check this http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4042/different-ways-to-earn-money-through-a-flash-game

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet is to put google ads on the page next to your game.

Comment: I agree. Also, I think it decreases value of games when there are ads embedded directly into games. UNLESS you have billboard in the game itself and you render Google Ads onto the Billboard ;)