# Ways to earn money through Flash games

Tags: flash, monetization, facebook, free-to-play

If you like developing flash games just for fun, why not make money through them?
There are different ways you can monetize your flash game:

- **In Game Ads:** Some common examples:

  - [Mochi Ads](http://www.mochiads.com/)
  - [gamejacket](http://www.gamejacket.com/)
  - [ad4game](http://www.ad4game.com/)
  - [CPMStar](http://www.cpmstar.com/)
  - [InviziAds](http://www.inviziads.com/)
- You can make money by **helping online gaming companies test and evaluate new games**. Many of those companies are seeking feedback and reviews of their newest games.
- **Find a sponsor and license your game.** One of the quickest yet hardest ways to make money from the flash games you create is to find a website who is willing to sponsor them. With a single sponsorship, an individual can make anywhere from $1000-$7000 for a game.

What are the best ads from these sites?

If the game will be in social websites like Facebook and MySpace, will it still be useful to try other sites?

Are there any other ways to earn money from a Flash game?

Comment: By what metric do you define best? Multiple questions should be separated into , well, multiple questions.

Comment: 1- revenue . 2- Western Union supported . 3- licence .4- when they pay .

Comment: Reaching the biggest audience

Comment: Other features/benefits of the site (eg integration APIs for high scores, micro payments, etc)

Comment: @Maged: I edited the title of the post to fix bad grammar, and because questions of the form "What's the best X?" are too subjective and unanswerable. Don't change it back again please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer question 3, check this out:
http://flashgamelicense.com/

This site hosts developers and sponsors. Developers submit a tender for offers from sponsors and sponsors in turn bid on your game. At the end of bidding, you choose the offer that best matches your desired terms (cash vs. terms of offer). Sponsors typically then get a license to use your game on their advertising website.

The author of Steambirds used this model pretty effectively, and describes his experiences with the process here: http://www.andymoore.ca/2010/03/steambirds-by-the-numbers/

Comment: Great article on making money with Flash games (written by one of the other guys who worked on Steambirds):
http://www.lostgarden.com/2009/07/flash-love-letter-2009-part-1.html

Answer (score 4):

Here's two methods not yet discussed:

Microtransactions! These are the cheap extras that people can buy from within a game. These can be extra weapons, more maps or even just the other half of the game itself (treating the free offering as a demo version). There are three 'big' companies that make this easy for developers. [Mochi's Coins](https://www.mochimedia.com/developers/coins.html) make it very easy, but they take 40% and that is *before* 'costs'. FlashGameLicense do [GamerSafe](http://GamerSafe.com) which has the same 40/60 split between them and the developer, *but* they have far, far less branding than Mochi. Mochi also forces the player to go to their site to buy Coins. Better, however, than both of these is Jambool's [Social Gold](http://www.jambool.com/socialgold/why_use_social_gold) which comes straight out of the Facebook microtransaction goldrush. There is no branding, users can buy your virtual currency straight in your game and you keep 90% of the profits. I'd use Social Gold if I were you. A few other notes, Sponsors hate microtransactions, so unless you have an awesome game, don't expect to get a good sponsorship while microtransactions are within your game. I think microtransactions work at their best when there is a multiplayer, or at least social, aspect to the game.

Self-publishing is a risky move, but it can pay off in the long term. This is where you host your games yourself. You are basically running a portal and revenue comes not just from in-game ads but from the ads scattered round the design of the site. Not a particularly *nice* option because you may have to spend a year or two just building an audience and having people return to your arcade daily. It's a massively competitive market too. On top of all that, administering that website really is a full time job and you'll probably do less game development as a result.